# How can I redirect non-IOS users to another page in my web app

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, redirect, detection

I'm working on a simple web app using jQuery mobile, and it is designed specifically for the iPhone. I am looking for a way to redirect anyone who isn't using an iOS device to another page.

I can't find any recent solutions that work. The closest I got was [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/), but the script did not work on my iPhone. It redirected me regardless of what device I was using.

Is there a solution that will fit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the script on that page redirects iPhone and iPod users to another site. It does not redirect non-iPhone/iPod users to another site. If that was the problem, simply change the javascript code to the following:

```
if (!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    location.replace("http://notiphoneoripod.yourdomain.com");
}
```

If you need to redirect iPad as well, use the following modification instead:

```
if (!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    location.replace("http://notiphoneoripodoripad.yourdomain.com");
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using a server-side programming language, such as PHP, you should do the redirect through that instead of client-side code. You can check using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in PHP.

Or if you want to do it directly on the server, if you're using Apache, you can add the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://notiphone.yourdomain.com [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do this -

1. Do the redirecting on the device. i.e. the client has the logic which url to hit. That's what you are mentioning above.
2. Best thing is to do it on server side at web-server. Webservers (like apache & nginx) are perfect for this. Before hitting a url from your client device, attach a header something like `XX-DEVICE-HEADER:IPOD` etc. then at webserver read this header & redirect as appropriate.